# Get active network adapter and set DNS via PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, networking, powershell

On Windows 10, I need to manually set my DNS server immediately after login. For some reason It seems DHCP blows away my manual settings on each reboot. :-(  )

I vary between using wifi and a cable (depending on whether I am at desk with dock).

This command works great:

```
Set-DNSClientServerAddress –interfaceIndex 25 –ServerAddresses (“127.0.0.1”,”1.1.1.2”)
```

How do I dynamically figure out the `interfaceIndex` for the currently active network connection?

**SOLUTION**

This is a work in progress (haven't figured out all the variations to look for the right adapter when on dock, etc) but it works on wifi (I have multiple vmware interfaces that are Up, need to filter them out!)

```
$adapterIndex = Get-NetAdapter | % { Process { If (( $_.Status -eq "up" ) -and ($_.Name -eq "Wi-Fi") ){ $_.ifIndex } }};

Set-DNSClientServerAddress –interfaceIndex $adapterIndex –ServerAddresses (“127.0.0.1”,”1.1.1.2”);
```

Comment: that is the purpose of DHCP - why not set a static IP to your computer and that way DHCP is disabled.

Comment: to answer your Question, this works for me ... >>> `(Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {-not $_.Virtual -and $_.Status -eq 'up'}).ifIndex` <<<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [get-netadapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=win10-ps) and get the value of the currently "***active***" network adapter per the status value of "***up***". Get the index value of that adapter dynamically using that value. Then use that as the value for the index in the `Set-DNSClientServerAddress` command to set the DNS addresses.

Please read more about the conditional logic and other techniques used to help get this detail dynamically in the **Supporting Resources** section.

### PowerShell

```
[int]$intix = Get-NetAdapter | % { Process { If ( $_.Status -eq "up" ) { $_.ifIndex } }};
Set-DNSClientServerAddress –interfaceIndex $intix –ServerAddresses ("127.0.0.1","1.1.1.2");
```

**Get-NetAdapter (Output Example)**

**Note:** Notice below that the `ifIndex` value `7` for the `Wi-Fi` named adapter is ***active and up***.

```
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Bluetooth Network Conn... Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Netw...      20 Disconnected 98-5F-D3-4B-59-C4         3 Mbps
Ethernet 3                Some Virtual Ethernet Adapter                14 Disabled     02-50-41-00-00-01         2 Gbps
Wi-Fi                     Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network ...       7 Up           98-5F-D3-4B-59-C3       468 Mbps
Ethernet 2                Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Cli...       4 Not Present  00-05-9A-3C-7A-00          0 bps
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-NetAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapter?view=win10-ps)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If()](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica ... if you have more than one adapter when you run the `Get-NetAdapter` command with a status of `up`, send me a pic link perhaps or edit the question and post there or tell me what you see otherwise. I'll be happy to figure out additional logic to extend on this should you have an issue. Getting to work from here is merely a trivial matter from here.

Comment: Thanks!  It is a bit more complex than you sketch, as I seem to have multiple VMWare related interfaces that are Up.  But, the following does the trick:  Get-NetAdapter | % { Process { If (( $_.Status -eq "up" ) -and ($_.Name -eq "Wi-Fi") ){ $_.ifIndex } }};

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you were able to figure out the trivial part to adjust for your specific needs. I would have been happy to further assist to make final environment specific adjustments.

Comment: The next step on this project is here: https://superuser.com/q/1626047/15466

Comment: For anybody needing this in a Dockerfile, the answer above works like a charm, but make sure to put the entire command as a one-liner in quotes: `RUN powershell "[int]$intix ....."`, and [obviously] make sure to escape the nested quotes.