# Powershell: How to figure out adapterIndex for interface to public?

Tags: powershell

I use a powershell script to [manually set my DNS](https://superuser.com/q/1625611/15466).

This works great, but as I move around between wifi and two different docking stations, the "ifIndex" from get-NetAdapter changes.

Just filtering for "Up" does not fly, because there are multiple Up interfaces (see below)

I am thinking I need to detect the interface that is both Up and is the route to public (e.g. on the route to google.com or something public).

How to do this?

```
PS C:\Users\joe> get-netadapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  TAP-ProtonVPN Windows Adapter V9             32 Disconnected 00-FF-F9-EE-DD-E4         1 Gbps
VMware Network Adapte...1 VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for ...      30 Up           00-50-56-EE-DD-01       100 Mbps
Wi-Fi                     Dell Wireless 1820A 802.11ac                 25 Up           C8-FF-28-EE-DD-4D       702 Mbps
VMware Network Adapte...8 VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for ...      24 Up           00-50-56-EE-DD-08       100 Mbps
Bluetooth Network Conn... Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Netw...      15 Disconnected C8-FF-28-EE-DD-4E         3 Mbps
vEthernet (Default Swi... Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter             22 Up           00-15-5D-EE-DD-F0        10 Gbps
vEthernet (WSL)           Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2          38 Up           00-15-5D-EE-DD-00        10 Gbps
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Drink More Pimp Juice IT](https://superuser.com/a/1626051/1248556) already mentioned a simple solution, which works if there is `only one network adapter` with a default gateway enabled and active.

If you have several network adapters enabled and active at the same time, which happens when you use a Laptop which doesn't disable or disconnect the WiFi adapter when connected via Ethernet, you will have two routes with a route metric of `0`, but with different InterfaceMetric's.

When the routes are manually configured it's also possible that the route metric of the default route isn't `0` at all.

## Solution

If you want to get the global default route of the Operating System in such cases, you have to take the total of `RouteMetric` and `InterfaceMetric` and use the default routes for IPv4 and IPv6 as destination filter.

The following command gets the default route of your OS using the IPv4 and IPv6 default routes.

```powershell
Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0', '::/0' |
    Sort-Object -Property { $_.InterfaceMetric + $_.RouteMetric } |
    Select-Object -First 1
```

> You can remove the IPv6 destination prefix `'::/0'` if you only want to determine the IPv4 route.

With the returning Interface Index `ifIndex` you can change the respective network adapter.
It's also possible to pipe the output above directly to `Get-NetAdapter` or any other cmdlet which accepts the InterfaceIndex as named property.

### PowerShell 6+

Beginning with PowerShell 6, we can simplify the command, since there is the new parameter `Top` available for `Sort-Object`.

```powershell
Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0', '::/0' |
    Sort-Object -Property { $_.InterfaceMetric + $_.RouteMetric } -Top 1
```

## Informative resources

- **Configure the Order of Network Interfaces**
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-subsystem/net-sub-interface-metric

  > When network traffic routes are chosen and you have configured the InterfaceMetric parameter of the Set-NetIPInterface command,
  > **the overall metric that is used to determine the interface preference is the sum of the route metric and the interface metric**.
  > Typically, the interface metric gives preference to a particular interface, such as using wired if both wired and wireless are available.
- **An explanation of the Automatic Metric feature for IPv4 routes**
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/automatic-metric-for-ipv4-routes

Comment: Awesome, thanks, perfect!  I modded it to this, as the IPV6 piece threw an error in my environment: Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0'  |
    Sort-Object -Property { $_.InterfaceMetric + $_.RouteMetric } |
    Select-Object -First 1 | % {Process { $_.ifIndex }} ;

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica You're welcome. Maybe you can share some details about your issue using IPv6 for others?. Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [get-netroute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netroute?view=win10-ps) to get the adapter index number with the `0` or `false` value which is the lowest metric and thus the adapter which should be the default for traffic to use.

## PowerShell

```
Get-NetRoute | ForEach-Object { Process { If (!$_.RouteMetric) { $_.ifIndex } } };
Set-DNSClientServerAddress –interfaceIndex $intix –ServerAddresses ("127.0.0.1","1.1.1.2");
```

#### Output Sample

**Command:** `Get-NetRoute | Select InterfaceAlias, InterfaceIndex, RouteMetric | FL`

```
InterfaceAlias : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
InterfaceIndex : 1
RouteMetric    : 256

InterfaceAlias : Wi-Fi 3
InterfaceIndex : 7
RouteMetric    : 0

InterfaceAlias : Local Area Connection* 12
InterfaceIndex : 14
RouteMetric    : 256

InterfaceAlias : Local Area Connection* 11
InterfaceIndex : 27
RouteMetric    : 256
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-NetRoute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netroute?view=win10-ps)
- [Set-DnsClientServerAddress](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/set-dnsclientserveraddress?view=win10-ps)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If()](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)

Comment: Whats the difference between `RouteMetric` and `ifMetric`?

Comment: @not2qubit What PS query you run to get it, I suspect it is a bool or true or false but cannot find with a quick google, and for example `Get-NetRoute  | Select ifMetric` nor `Select *` show me this property. I'm not sure what it indicates or represents, but if you give me a query to show it, that may help me further figure it out.

Comment: I found the crazy answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-tcpip-interfaces-interface-ipv4settings-metric). *`Metric` specifies the interface metric for the IPv4 protocol. When routes are chosen, the overall metric used to determine the preference is the sum of the `RouteMetric ` and the `ifMetric`.* Although this does not answer my question.

Comment: Use: `Get-NetRoute |Select-Object * |Select-Object ifIndex,DestinationPrefix,RouteMetric,InterfaceMetric,NextHop |ft`

Comment: I see, basically.... I think route metrics are associated with specific routes in the routing table, and the quality of those routes. Whereas interface metrics are associated with network interfaces,  and the quality or cost of using those interfaces. Basically, routing protocols use these metrics to make decisions about how to route packets through a network. I also found: https://serverfault.com/questions/399391/interface-metric-vs-route-metric @not2qubit Some algorithm used to pick the best route using the two.